# Difference between CPython _io_open_impl and _Py_open_impl

Tags: python, windows, cpython, python-internals

Working my way through some low level implementations in CPython 3 and I started with the built-in `open` method; a quick `help(open)` stated that its an alias to the `io.open` method. From there I can resolve the following:

> _io/_iomodule.c -> _io_open_impl -> _io/fileio.c -> _io_FileIO__init__impl

The `_io_open_impl` takes the string flags that are defined in [_wfopen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fopen-wfopen?view=vs-2019) and applies the macros defined in [_wopen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/open-wopen?view=vs-2019#return-value), to which the latter is called in `_io_FileIO__init__impl`. Therefore, I would reasonably conclude that:

> In CPython 3, the built-in `open` uses `_wopen` underneath on Windows

Now where I've run into a bit of confusion is when I discovered `_Py_open_impl` in *Python/fileutils.c* and I don't understand its purpose; the same file subsequently defines `_Py_wfopen` and `_Py_fopen`. Searching through the repository I can see that these methods are called in *Modules/main.c* but seldom elsewhere. So...

> **If `_io_open_impl` is for opening files with CPython, what is `_Py_open_impl` for?**

The best conclusion I can reason about is that its used for code related to compiling and running the interpreter itself and is not part of the Python language/syntax.

Comment: `_Py_open` and `_Py_open_noraise` are not in the stable API. They're used internally on POSIX systems, particularly for opening device files such as "/dev/zero" and "/dev/urandom". They're not used in Windows -- at least not by CPython itself -- because they call MSVC `open`, which is limited to the process active codepage, which is usually a legacy encoding such as codepage 1252. CPython uses wide-character `_wopen` in Windows, with UTF-16 encoded filenames.

Comment: @ErykSun By stable API, I'm guessing you mean the standard library for a release? Therefore, by internally you mean as part of the compiled interpreter? If so, that makes sense that these calls are defined and used where directives are placed throughout various .c files in "cpython/Python" and "cpython/Modules". Although, it appears that `_Py_open` is part of some of the modules in the standard library, such as `mmap` where it makes a call to "/dev/zero"; is that still considered "internal"?

Comment: @ErykSun Or did you mean the C-API as the "stable API"?

Comment: Generally, C functions prefixed with `_Py` in the [C API](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/intro.html) are internal functions that are exported only for use by the interpreter and extension modules in the standard library. In Windows, this means that you'll find that `_Py_open` and `_Py_open_noraise` are exported by "python39.dll" (for Python 3.9). Most `_Py` prefixed functions are not in the [stable API](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/stable.html) (i.e. the limited API, corresponding to a stable ABI), so they're not exported by "python3.dll".

Comment: @ErykSun Thank you for clarifying what the `_Py` functions were used for! Random tangent, but if I wanted to understand the structure of CPython (i.e. how all the .h/.c files work together), any recommendations? For example, I can navigate it quite well but I have no idea how it all ties together; like why is the `main.c` in "Modules" and not "Python"? Basic knowledge would alleviate me asking questions such as this one.

Comment: The interpreter is designed to support embedding in applications, which won't necessarily execute a `__main__` script from command-line arguments via `Py_Main`. As to the project layout, recently there has been a lot of reorganization and a complete rewrite of the initialization code. It would be better for you to begin learning at the C API level if you're interested in the low-level implementation details, developing extension modules, or embedding the interpreter. Find and read the source files as needed while learning.

Comment: @ErykSun So the interpreter source code doesn't have a traditional `void main()` call?

Comment: The "python" program is in "Programs/python.c". It calls `Py_Main` in Windows and `Py_BytesMain` in Unix. The entrypoint is `wmain` in Windows, which provides a wide-character command-line argument array. (The real process entrypoint is `wmainCRTStartup`. Unlike Unix, Windows programs are passed a wide-character command line, and the C runtime is responsible for parsing it into an argument array. For the classic `main` entrypoint, which Python does not use, the CRT also has to encode the arguments to `char` strings using the process active codepage, which is likely a legacy codepage.)

Comment: @ErykSun So whats the difference between the inclusions in the stable API for cpython/Include/fileutils.h and cpython/Include/cpython/fileutils.h? The latter makes available `_Py_write` which is later defined in Python/fileutils.c and used in `Modules/_io/fileio.c` which is used by the object returned from `_io_open_impl` which is the `FileIO_type` object.